# Save current terminal scrollback to file?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have been looking for an answer to this and not finding anything which makes me think it's not possible but ...

Is it possible to save the current Gnome Terminal scrollback buffer to a file?

I know that I can do something like `command > output.txt` to redirect all output to a file, or `command | tee output.txt` to split the output to the terminal as well as to a file. What I am trying to do is capture this after the fact. I'd like to save the current terminal tab's scrollback contents to a file.

Comment: `kitty` is one terminal program that can do this, unfortunately fonts look terrible (no subpixel rendering)

Comment: Thanks, @jberryman. Good to know.

Comment: XTerm can also do it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602960

Answer (score 67, accepted):

After a bit of playing around I've discovered that you can:

- `triple-click` the last line
- hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + `click` first line
- copy with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> (or `right-click` > 'Copy')

Now paste it into a text file ...or, using `xsel` you can shove your clipboard into a new file by just popping open a new tab and doing:

```
xsel -o > out.txt
```

(To install `xsel` do `sudo apt-get install xsel`)

### WARNING

An unlimited scrollback can get *huge* and attempting to select all of it for copying will be slow and could even exceed memory limits. See comments below.

Comment: Highlighting can be done more easily: `Edit` -> `Select All`.

Comment: This is a great answer cause it makes you realize you can use `triple-click the last line` and `shift + home or the scrollbar` to go to the exact location you want for the beginning of the output.

Comment: Warning: Don't try this with a large scollback (many megabytes) as it might hang X (happened to me).

Comment: With many megabytes, slow processing is to be expected. Be patient and let the computer work. "Give it a second! It's going to space! Can you give it a second to get back from space?!"

Comment: I just tried to copy a large scrollback (rsync output from backing up a couple 2TB drives overnight) using the `Edit` -> `Select All` method to capturing the output. It's been 25-30 minutes now and Gnome Terminal is still locked up. Using Byobu, I was able to start up `top` to see that Gnome Terminal  is still running (increasing CPU time); currently using over 4.176g of RAM and slowly climbing. So, yeah, with a very large scrollback, it's gonna take a while. X is still running (and Chrome, YouTube, Nautilus, Byobu, etc.) but Gnome Terminal is gonna need a minute. I should've planned better.

Comment: My Gnome Terminal (all 3 windows with multiple tabs) crashed when I did `xsel -o > out.txt`, and then Cinnamon crashed as well :/

Comment: Wow, Bloke. You might want to look into that a little more (hardware issues, Cinnamon bugs, etc.). I use this trick quite often now and without any trouble. I consistently have several windows open and several tabs in each window. I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3.

Comment: @[chicks](https://askubuntu.com/users/371118/chicks), Thanks for the edits!

Comment: Just noticed that newer version (tested on 20.04 = GNOME 3.36.2) of the GNOME terminal also offer a "Copy as HTML" right-click option, which is useful if you like to preserve any colouring and highlighting.

Comment: Nice! Thanks, [sxc731](https://askubuntu.com/users/145568/sxc731).

Comment: @KevinCox Yup, just discovered that the hard way. I wanted to copy the scrollback (including the whole output of `tree /`) and it hung my laptop untill `oom-killer` killed the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, @Lampe2020. Yeah, you have to be careful with that. An unlimited scrollback can get huge.

Answer (score 9):

`script` command is appropriate when you want to save a terminal session to a file and display it later.  When you call `script` it launches your shell, and when you are done, just type in exit. Everything will be in `typescript` file unless you specify otherwise.

For instance,

```
xieerqi:$ echo "Hello, Karl Wilbur"
Hello, Karl Wilbur

xieerqi:$ date
2015年 10月 27日 星期二 11:38:15 MDT

xieerqi:$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      115247656 80939384  28430924  75% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2914832        4   2914828   1% /dev
tmpfs             585216     1100    584116   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2926072      328   2925744   1% /run/shm
none              102400       52    102348   1% /run/user

xieerqi:$ exit
Script done, file is typescript
xieerqi@eagle:~$ cat typescript 
Script started on 2015年10月27日 星期二 11时37分55秒

xieerqi:$ echo "Hello, Karl Wilbur"
Hello, Karl Wilbur

xieerqi:$ date
2015年 10月 27日 星期二 11:38:15 MDT

xieerqi:$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      115247656 80939384  28430924  75% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             2914832        4   2914828   1% /dev
tmpfs             585216     1100    584116   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             2926072      328   2925744   1% /run/shm
none              102400       52    102348   1% /run/user

xieerqi:$ exit

Script done on 2015年10月27日 星期二 11时38分18秒
```

There may be control characters in the typescript file though ,such as from the `ls` comand, so use `cat typescript | col -b > outputfile.txt` command to redirect clean output to file

Comment: Thanks, but this is something that needs to be done *before* you have collected valuable information in your terminal. I needed an after-the-fact solution.

Comment: This is very good to know though. I'll give it a shot in the future.

Comment: @KarlWilbur :) I'm sure you will find it useful. I use it a lot for my programming homework. There's actually a way to dump what's on screen in TTY consoles, but gnome-terminal is a bit more tricky

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I try to implement this into my python script, but I cant exit from script doing "os.system("exit"). However it does exit from terminal and save output to file.

Comment: @mtkilic The `script` command launches a separate process, so your python script being a parent of the subprocess is waiting for child to exit. It's meant more for interactive sessions, but if you do want to record a session in Python interpreter, start the `script` command first and launch interpreter second. The command should also have `-c` flag so you could call `script -c python` but double check with `man script`.

Comment: by the way, `system()` isn't recommended. Look into `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()` with `shell=False` flag

Comment: This is useful - even if it didn't answer the question exactly.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this after the fact as well. You're looking for Virtual Console Memory (`man vcs` contains more info and a couple of examples).

In your case, if you're is working on a virtual terminal trough /dev/tty1, the following snippet will let you store the backlog in a file `output-file`:

```
cat /dev/vcs1 >output-file
```

Note that the device numbers of tty1 and vcs1 match.

Edit: I should note that this only works for virtual terminals and not for pseudo terminals (pseudo terminals are used to implement terminal emulators like gnome-terminal, xterm etc see `man pts` for more info).

Comment: This is potentially a very useful answer for me, except for the fact that I'm unclear on how to get the correct `vcs`. the `tty` command -> `/dev/pts/0`. As I read your answer, that means I should be able to get my scrollback with `cat /dev/vcs0`. Unfortunately, there **is no vcs0***. Could you please clarify?