# what happened to the "save contents" command in gnome terminal?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

In the help system for terminal in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, under *Terminal>Working with Text* the following is stated:

> **Save contents**
>
> You can save all the output from a Terminal tab or window to a text file. This may be useful if
>
> you have to submit the terminal output as debugging information.
>
> Go to File.
>
> Select Save Contents….
>
> Choose your desired directory and enter a filename.
>
> Click Save.

Under File, I see only New Tab, New Window, Close Tab and Close Window.  How do I get the save contents command to appear in the UI?   If the help system is not authoritative, what is an authoritative source of information on the Ubuntu gnome terminal?

I did see [this helpful post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690703/save-current-terminal-scrollback-to-file) as a workaround, but I am wondering whether the help system out of date or whether the UI has a defect.

Comment: I see this menu entry for `xfce` under the Terminal menu, might that be true for Ubuntu as well

Comment: @aman Under the terminal menu in the terminal app, I am seeing `change profile - read-only - reset - reset and clear - 1 80 x 24,` etc.  Is that what you meant?