# Save current terminal scrollback to file

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have been looking for an answer to this and not finding anything which makes me think it's not possible but ...

Is it possible to save the current Gnome Terminal scrollback buffer to a file?

I know that I can do something like `command > output.txt` to redirect all output to a file, or `command | tee output.txt` to split the output to the terminal as well as to a file. What I am trying to do is capture this after the fact. I'd like to save the current terminal tab's scrollback contents to a file.

Comment: This is a word-for-word copy of [this question from 4 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690703/save-current-terminal-scrollback-to-file). Does the accepted solution no longer work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do the following to save it in a file:

- Highlight the text you want to be in the file by `Edit->Select All`
- You can also highlight by following

  - `triple-click` the last line
  - press `shift` + `home`
  - `shift` + `click` the line you want to copy
  - Now just press `cntrl`+`shift` + `c` to copy.
- You can then just save the copied text in a .txt file.
  You can also use `xsel`, just type the following in your terminal:

  sudo apt-get install xsel

Now type `xsel -o > filename.txt`

The `filename.txt`  will be the name of the file, where you want the  save the current Gnome Terminal scroll back buffer.

The newer version, i.e. `GNOME 3.36.2` comes with a feature, `copy as HTML` which makes it possible to preserve any coloring and highlighting.